# PHP cURL to send to IP range

Tags: php, curl

I will preface this by saying I'm a Lighting Designer not a programmer so be nice!

I have this API call that I've generated from Postman. Short of copy and pasting it over and over, what's the most effective way to send this call to multiple IPs addresses in a range, factoring in that some IPs might not exist?

i.e. I want to send the below call to every IP from 2.4.7.1 through 2.4.7.99 however 2.4.7.56 may not exist as a device

TIA

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://2.4.7.1/api/profile/10/recall',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
  "keep_ip_settings": false
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Wrap the whole thing into a `for` loop that goes from 1 to 99, and dynamically insert the loop variable in the last segment of the IP address ...? _"however 2.4.7.56 may not exist as a device"_ - so that request will simply fail then, no biggie.

Comment: As above...use a loop. Computers are great at repeating themselves

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: SO is not a programming school. If you're not a programmer, you need to learn programming basics like loops, or find someone else to do it for you.

Comment: Change `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0` to the length the request should hang for if no connection is made, 10 seconds maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You may put the curl statements in a function (e.g callcurl) so that you can just use a loop to call the function.

The loop can simply be (ignoring 2.4.7.56 by a `if condition`):

```
$index=1;

while ($index <=99){
   if ($index !=56) {
        callcurl("2.4.7.".$index);
      } 
$index++;
}
```

So the whole code will be:

```
<?php

function callcurl($ip) {
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://'. $ip . '/api/profile/10/recall',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
  "keep_ip_settings": false
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
}


$index=1;

while ($index <=99){
   if ($index !=56) {
        callcurl("2.4.7.".$index);
      } 
$index++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php

$baseIP = '2.4.7.';
$apiEndpoint = '/api/profile/10/recall';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++) {
    $currentIP = $baseIP . $i;
    
    // Check if the IP exists (you can adjust the timeout based on your needs)
    if (filter_var($currentIP, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && pingIP($currentIP, 1)) {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://' . $currentIP . $apiEndpoint,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
                "keep_ip_settings": false
            }',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept: application/json'
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        echo "API call sent to: $currentIP\n";
        echo $response . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Skipping non-existing IP: $currentIP\n";
    }
}

function pingIP($ip, $timeout) {
    $cmd = "ping -c 1 -W $timeout $ip";
    exec($cmd, $output, $result);
    return $result === 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers. Explain what you've done and why